# Embedded Set,Link Set in OType in OrientDb

Tags: java, orientdb

Can Someone give me sample code of using above mentioned types in orientdb as value to an index.I am using Document API of **OrientDb-2.0.5**.
What is the difference between Embedded Set and Link Set?How to choose between them?Are there any performance differences between them?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, we need to know what the following mean in **OrientDB** (this information is available [here](http://orientdb.com/docs/last/Types.html)):

- **Embedded Record**: *The Record is contained inside the owner. The contained Record has no RecordId*
- **Link**: *Link to another Record*

This example will clarify it:

```
private static void orientDBCollections() throws IOException {
    dropDBIfExists(URL, USER);
    createDBIfDoesNotExist(URL, USER);

    OPartitionedDatabasePool pool = new OPartitionedDatabasePool(URL, USER, USER);
    try (ODatabaseDocument db = pool.acquire()) {
        OSchema schema = db.getMetadata().getSchema();
        OClass classA = schema.createClass("A");
        OClass classB = schema.createClass("B");
        classA.createProperty("embMap", OType.EMBEDDEDMAP, classB);
        classA.createProperty("linkMap", OType.LINKMAP, classB);
        classA.createProperty("embSet", OType.EMBEDDEDSET, classB);
        classA.createProperty("linkSet", OType.LINKSET, classB);

        ODocument docA = new ODocument("A");
        ODocument docB = new ODocument("B");
        docB.field("name", "nanana");

        Map<String, ODocument> map = new HashMap();
        map.put("thekey", docB);
        docA.field("embMap", map, OType.EMBEDDEDMAP);
        docA.field("linkMap", map, OType.LINKMAP);

        Set<ODocument> set = new HashSet();
        set.add(docB);
        docA.field("embSet", set, OType.EMBEDDEDSET);
        docA.field("linkSet", set, OType.LINKSET);

        docA.save();
    } finally {
        pool.close();
    }
}
```

After this, **SELECT FROM A** from Studio, Console, etc... and you'll understand.

Comment: When we say docA.save();will it save docB also with seperate RecordId without explicitly mentioning docB.save().If so how does it satisfy Embedded Map case where it shouldn't be saved.

Comment: In order to **docA** be saved correctly, **docB** has to be saved too, I guess that's the logic they implemented.